# Kohana framework with ORM create custome where

Tags: orm, kohana

I am using Kohana framework 3, and I need to create a query

I need add one where part only if variable is true, otherwise I don't need one WHERE part.

How add php if script in query?

What I need:

```
ORM::factory('test')
->select( array('name', 'surname') )
->where('id', '=', $user->id)

if ($active == 1) {
    ->where('status', '=', 1)
}

->order_by('docid', 'DESC')->find_all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = ORM::factory('test')
->select( array('name', 'surname') )
->where('id', '=', $user->id);

if ($active == 1) {
    query->where('status', '=', 1);
}

$query->order_by('docid', 'DESC')->find_all();
```